# is there a DRM compatable browser that is able to be fully up to date?

Tags: pi-3, web-browsers

i am wanting to use my RPi3 for a media device at home but i can not use things like YouTube TV or other sites that require DRM support...

i know Firefox has DRM support but the browser isn't up to date and YouTube TV can see that.

YouTube TV is the thing i want to use the most on the RPi3 but i would like to use Netflix and Hulu as well.

i have using a user agent spoofer to try to trick the page to load but it didn't work

Comment: AFAIK your best shot is to use [Chromium](https://thepi.io/how-to-watch-netflix-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: the issue with that is the newest version available that has the drm module in it is 52 or something like that... and 59 is what is the newest version....and i dont know how to recompile it with Widevine enabled for the rpi...

nor do i know how to recompile the newest firefox source for armfh (what the package names say for all the rpi install packages)